# SVN Installation and adding user

Tags: useradd, subversion

I installed SVN in my linux server a year back by following some documentation online and I created two users to my svn repository. I need to add few more users to my repository and I completely forgot what I did for installing and creating the user. I lost my notes and I dont have great memory.

First thing is I should know where did I install subversion or svn.

When I ran the command

```
find / -name subversion i see below
```

I got the results like

```
/home/svn
/home/svn/csvn/bin/svn
/home/svn/csvn/lib/svn-python.2.6/svn
/home/svn/csvn/lib/svn-python.2.4/svn
/home/svn/csvn/lib/svn-python.2.7/svn
/home/svn/csvn/lib/viewvc/vclib/svn
/home/svn/csvn/lib/svn-python.2.5/svn
/home/beawlp/svn
/var/spool/mail/svn
/usr/bin/svn
```

beawlp is my username.

Second thing is I should know how to add a svn user.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you don't need to know where you installed svn. You can still use svn from the command line regardless where it is. If you are still itnerested to know where the binary file is use `which svn`.

Second, there is no thing as *svn user*. You just create an ordinary user (a system user) like you do `adduser <username>`, then add the new user to the group of the repo. Voila. You are done! Check the following list of commands.

```
adduser <username> # creates a user
ls -ld /path/to/repo # this should print something like this: -rw-rw-r-- 1 foo bar   45 Sep 15 17:55 repo. bar is the group name.
usermod -aG bar <username> # use the group name instead of bar.
```

Comment: adduser <username> sounds like it created user successfully. but how to add this user to the group of the repo ?

Comment: Updated answer.

Comment: Thank You joker. Sorry about my ignorance. I got svn group with the command ls -ld and when I tried to usermod command as you said, I get below .. usermod -aG svn
Usage: usermod [options] LOGIN
Options:
..etc

Comment: Yes. The last command was missing the username at the end of the command. Updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks Joker. Sounds like this would fix the issue. I have installed svn under non-root user and dont have access to create users. I might need to install svn under root and do the steps as you said. Thanks for your support.

Comment: You can still run the installation by prepending every command that needs privilege leverage `sudo`. So, that would be `sudo apt-get install svn` if you are using Ubuntu or the like OSs, `sudo yum install svn` if you are using CentOS and the like OSs.